Axions stars mass and radii
Are there any stringent bounds on the possible mass and radii of axion stars?
Some theories do predict the existence of axions or axion-like particles (in the mood these days). Given the fact the coupling and mass of axions are quite stringent, I wonder the above question, and its implications.
*Bonus: Can axions/axion stars be ALL the dark matter?Should we expect a cosmic axion background?

https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.11473 gives some mass-radius curves, but if I understood it right, it depends a bit on how you choose to model the system. Given that they have a minimum and maximum mass, dark matter in this case would be a mix of free axions, axion stars, and black holes.

Axion stars can weigh from $10^{-12}$ to $10^{-2}$ solar masses and their radii can range from meters to kilometers.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
